# When simulation on true device, database error: SQLiteDB - failed to copy writable version of DB

Tags: ios, xcode

I`m using databases in my swift project.
Everyting was fine when I did simulation on simulator,  but when i tried to run my app on my truth ios device, the error showed below

> Database path:
>   /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7751C273-D7B4-4AE1-9593-775755C0F0D2/Documents/data.db
>
> SQLiteDB - failed to copy writable version of DB!
>
> Error -  the file “data.db” couldn’t be opened because there is no
>   such file.

anyone has any solution?

Comment: One difference b/w device and simulator is that device is case sensitive, but MacOS (generally) is not. Check the capitalization used in the file names.

Comment: The file is missing. Did you copy the file in Xcode - Target - Build Phases?

Comment: Try deploy on other simulators. Does it work or you get the same error?